# Storage does not failover in Windows cluster

Tags: sql-server-2014, clustering, failover, storage

I created a lab setup for a 2 node cluster using Windows 2012 R2. I first configured the quorum and performed a failover between both the nodes, the quorum would also map to the respective node. But whenever I added the data and the log drives and tried to do a failover, they are not getting mapped to the respective nodes. What am I missing here? These are the steps I followed

1) Create New Virtual SCSI drive from the Server manager
2) Adding both the Nodes as targets with their IP addresses
3) Initialized SCSI target from both the nodes 
4) Open Disk management and format the drives to MBR->NTFS-64k allocation
5) In the failover cluster manager -> add the disks to the cluster

Is there something else which I need to do? Please refer to the screenshots below

SCSI creation from Domain controller :

[image]

Quorum as part of cluster resources 
[image]

All disks on SQL1 before failover

[image]

Disks on SQL1 after failover to SQL2. Notice that the Data and log drives are still on SQL1. I did not create any Cluster Shared Volumes here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post screen shots of the storage from Failover Cluster Manager? I'm interested in seeing the data and log drives in Failover Cluster Manager.